# What are all possible ways to add strings to the .rdata section of a Binary Executable?

Tags: section, code-generation

I was wondering what are all the possible ways people can mess with the executable's `.rdata` strings ?

Because I've actualy seen it .. But I do not have any idea how they do that.

Some random dude made like a copy of My executable but with more strings (Files Names) on an [x] offset that falls into the `.rdata` section, which caused the Executable to map more files in the memory ...

How is that even possible ?

Comment: i think you need to read the section and resize it or change fix size string, then you need to point to the string from your code, in the right location address...